# Sum numbers in a delimited text and return average

Tags: text, sum, formula, libreoffice-calc

I have the following numbers as text in a cell:

```
"12-14-14-16-18-10"
```

And now I need to calculate the average but I do not want to create extra columns since the length of the data varies.

Is there any way to do this using a formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but let me add my two cents. Use `FILTERXML` and some `XPATH` magic =)

---

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&REGEX(A1;"-";"</s><s>";"g")&"</s></t>";"sum(//s) div count(//s)")
```

[image]

---

We could even implement a check on numeric nodes:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&REGEX(A1;"-";"</s><s>";"g")&"</s></t>";"sum(//s[.*0=0]) div count(//s[.*0=0])")
```

[image]

---

Looking at this I find it unfortunate `Excel` won't allow direct manipulation inside the expression itself. Suprised `LibreOffice` does!

Answer (score 1):

In other words: you want to split the string value by the "-" character and calculate the average of its elements? AFAIK the only way to solve this is using a small macro (AKA user-defined function), since LO Calc doesn't provide a split/tokenize function on spreadsheet level.

A quick and dirty solution may look as follows:

```vb
Function split_average(a)
    Dim theArray(UBound(Split(a, "-"))) As Integer
    theArray = Split(a, "-")
    Dim SumVal As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(theArray)
        SumVal = SumVal + theArray(i)
    Next i
    split_average = SumVal / (UBound(theArray) + 1)
End Function
```

Of course, there's no type checking and so on, so try on your own risk. To use it, just copy it into the StarBasic Standard module, save, and call it inside your spreadsheet using `=split_average(A1)`. For user-defined functions in general, see [the LO Calc docs](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/User-Defined_Functions).